# Symfony 5 + Webpack Encore + Bootstrap Table not exporting

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, bootstrap-table

I am trying to add an exportable [Bootstrap Table](https://bootstrap-table.com/) for each entity. But the [export button](https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/view-source) is being displayed but still, it has no action while clicking over it.

[image]

I thought this could be some library issue but I guess the error is in my code.

Since its [installation documentation](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/getting-started/download/) is not "big" I will write the steps I followed:

1. Ran `yarn add bootstrap-table`
2. Added jQuery and other [table export libraries](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#extensions/export.html#view-source) inside `/assets/app.js`:

   ```js
   import '../css/app.scss';
   import $ from 'jquery';
   global.$ = global.jQuery = $;

   import 'bootstrap';
   import './tableExport.min.js';
   import 'bootstrap-table';
   import './bootstrap-table-export.min.js';
   import './bootstrap-table-locale-es.js';

   import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
   import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js';


   console.log('Webpack compilado');
   ```
3. To avoid some errors, this might be redundant with the previous step, I added `jquery` as a global variable to `webpack.config.js`:

   ```js
   .autoProvidejQuery()
   .autoProvideVariables({
       $: 'jquery',
       jQuery: 'jquery',
       'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
   })
   ```
4. Added the HTML to the template: `<table class="table"></table>`
5. Added the JavaScript to the template:

   ```
   $('.table').bootstrapTable({
            columns: [
                {% block jsTableColumns %}{% endblock %},
                {
                    field: 'show',
                    title: 'Acciones',
                    formatter,
                    align: 'center'
                }
            ],
            showExport: true,
            search: true,
            url: '/api/{% block jsApi %}{% endblock %}.json',
            pagination: true,
            {% block jsTableOptions %}{% endblock %}
        })
   ```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide a demo? The "export button" hyperlink leads to a blank Bootstrap Table editor.

Comment: I don't think so, I should replicate a whole Symfony installation. That's why I added the image. I will try how to "replicate" such an installation...

Comment: Can you check the URL behind the button? Is it generated correctly? If so, try accessing the URL directly and check your logs for any errors. I don't know bootstrapTable, but maybe the url returns a 4xx/5xx error and it has special handling for these errors

Comment: I already did that, there is no action even being triggered in developer console. Nothing happens when clicking over it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution I found is here https://symfony.com/blog/moving-script-inside-head-and-the-defer-attribute

In the .config/packages/webpack_encore.yaml replace defer to false

```
webpack_encore:
    script_attributes:
         defer: false
```